# Задача: Можно ли из слова сделать палиндром?

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки

Задача следующая:

> Можно ли из слова сделать палиндром? Убирать можно только подстроку из
> трех символов (т.е. 3 символа подряд. Ни больше ни меньше.) Количество
> таких операций не ограничено. Палиндромом строка считается, если ее значение равно ее перевернутому значению. Т.е. это не обязательно должно быть слово(одинаковые буквы или цифры). количество символов в строке не больше 10^6

Я попытался решить, но у меня не получилось.

Пример:

Ввод: arcsinus
Вывод: YES

Ввод: abcde
Вывод: NO

```
s = input()
ch =list(s)
m=[]
if s == s[::-1]:
    print("YES")
else:
    for i in s:
        if ch.count(i)>1:
            c = s.find(i)
            lent = len(s)
            if c%3==0:
                k = s.find(i,c)
                if (k - c)%4 ==0:
                    m.append(i)
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
    if len(m) > 1:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Если в слове *3n* символов, удалим их все...

Comment: В этом и проблема, нужно сделать так, чтобы было хотя бы 2 одинаковых символа в строке. Тогда оно будет считаться палиндромом, иначе - нет.

Comment: Полностью  с вами согласен, но преподаватель - нет)

Comment: Я что то кручу верчу и не могу понять, какое слово полиндром можно сделать из слова *arcsinus*?

Comment: @SwaD, `arcsinus` -> `-arc`, `-inu` -> `ss`.

Comment: Не понимаю, можете разжевать?

Comment: Вольные фразы по-прежнему позволяют предполагать, что вы приводите свой пересказ условия, а не точно то, что задано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте попробуем так:

Палиндром длиной не менее 2 можно собрать, если существуют позиции какого-то символа:

```
Если len mod 3 = 0, то позиции  3*p и 3*q+2, q>=p          (*a*b*a*)
Если len mod 3 = 2, то позиции  3*p и 3*q+1, q>=p          (*a*a*)
Если len mod 3 = 1, то позиции  одного символа 3*p и 3*q,
     второго (или того же) 3*u+1 и 3*v+2, p<=u<=v<q        (*a*b*b*a*)
```

Вроде все случаи собрал?

Для проверки можно хранить позиции символов в словаре `{char:[positions]...}`, однако проще и выгоднее вместо списка позиций иметь просто признак(и) того, что символ уже встречался при индексе нужной кратности.

Алгоритм линейный

```
from collections import defaultdict
def palpossible(s):
    dc = defaultdict(int)
    mod3 = len(s) % 3
    if mod3 in [0, 2]:
        m = 2 - mod3 // 2   # 2 => 1; 0 =>2
        for i, c in enumerate(s):
            if i%3==0:
                dc[c]=1
            elif i%3==m:
                if dc[c]:
                    return True
    else:
        m12 = False
        for i, c in enumerate(s):
            if i%3==0:
                if (dc[c]&1) and m12:    # a b b a
                    return True
                dc[c] |= 1
            elif i%3==1:
                dc[c] |=  2
            else:
                if (dc[c]&2):
                    m12 = True      # нашли a b b
    return False

print(palpossible("aba"), end = " ")
print(palpossible("123a456b789aCDE"), end = " ")
print(palpossible("123a456c78a9CDE"))

print(palpossible("aa"), end = " ")
print(palpossible("123a456a789"), end = " ")
print(palpossible("123a45a6789"))

print(palpossible("abba"), end = " ")
print(palpossible("123a456b789bCDEaFGH"),end = " ")
print(palpossible("123a45b6789bCDEaFGH"), end = " ")
print(palpossible("aabb"))
```

Результат

```
True True False
True True False
True True False False
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Если речь о комбинации "abab", то такое правильно даёт False